# Search results eat up formatted code

Tags: bug, status-deferred, search, code-formatting

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3961546+iron+flash shows this:

[image]

Navigating to [that response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183325/meteor-image-doesnt-show-up-on-every-pages/28184751#28184751) reveals that the `{{> yield}}` code markup was removed.

[image]